# Change OpenVPN client's default route

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

When setting up a test openvpn client on Ubuntu (using this guide), the client sets a route which tunnels all traffic through the vpn.

For example, when I connect to the vpn from Ubuntu, this is what `netstat -nr` shows:

```
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.9        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 tun0
10.8.0.1        10.8.0.9        255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 tun0
10.8.0.9        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 tun0
...
```

I believe the first line is tunnelling everything through the vpn, correct? When I compare this to the output of the same command from my OSX machine:

```
10.8.0.1/32        10.8.0.5           UGSc            1        0    tun0
10.8.0.5           10.8.0.6           UH              2       33    tun0
...
```

I don't have that rule. Is there a way for me to push a command to delete that route from the client? What are my other options here?

Answer (score 7):

I assume you're using the NetworkManager GUI.  It seems that its default behaviour is to override the default route, even if the OpenVPN server isn't pushing it.

You can fix that behaviour by editing the VPN connection and on the **IPv4** settings tab select the '**Routes...**' button.
You'll see an option called '**Use this connection only for resources on this network**'.  Make sure that's enabled and then restart your VPN.  That should sort you out.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the respective lines in yor .ovpn file. You may need root rights (sudo) for this.
You should have received the file *whateveritiscalled.ovpn* together with your certificates from your openvpn provider. Open the file with vi, gedit or another text editor and search for the lines below:

```
# The hostname/IP and port of the server.
# You can have multiple remote entries
# to load balance between the servers.
```

Under these lines you can add the IP and / or hostname of the route you want to use or is recommended by your vpn provider. Save the file.

Comment: This is quite vague. Can you explain *how* to do this? What are the "respective lines"? Where is the .ovpn file?

Comment: I knew this much, my question was more geared towards "how" I should format the line(s) to add those rules in those files.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hope it is understandable.